# Кастомный механизм копирования в TextView

Tags: android, textview

Всем привет. Требуется создать TextView в котором можно будет выбрать лишь одно слово. Также будет фильтр не позволяющий выбрать слово с определенными запрещенными символами. Помимо этого текст скопировать будет нельзя. При выделение должно быть кастомное меню с кнопками. Скажите, есть ли в андроиде такое? Может кто использовал библиотеку с подобным функционалом? Подскажите куда копать, делать кастомный TextView?

Comment: Звучит как `on(Long)Click`+`SpannableString`+`PopupWindow`. Не знаю, как правильно собрать эту конструкцию (в основном, как отслеживать позицию/слово клика), но смотрел бы в эту сторону

Comment: @Jarvis_J, спасибо. основная трудность в том, что у текствью уже есть спаны :)

Comment: запрещать пользователю делать какие-то действия мягко говоря не очень хорошо, он может не ожидать такого поведения. Возможно вам подойдет такой вариант, что он будет копировать все как хочет а потом при вставке куда-то все запрещенные слова будут или вырезаться, или помечаться ххх, в ClipBoard. как такая альтернатива?

Comment: @SweetDev, фильтр при вставке уже есть. Мне нужно сделать не копирование а выделение с окном-попапом.. Но я уже начал делать, как получится - тут ответ напишу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем, дизайн сменили и сошлось все на создании кастомного `LinkMovementMethod`. Взял код из библиотеки `BetterLinkMovementMethod` и переписал под себя

```
class BetterLinkMovementMethod private constructor() : LinkMovementMethod() {

    var onLinkClickListener: OnLinkClickListener? = null
    var wordSelectionListener: OnWordSelectionListener? = null
    private var touchDownX = 0
    private var touchDownY = 0
    private val touchedLineBounds = RectF()
    private var isUrlHighlighted: Boolean = false
    private var clickableSpanUnderTouchOnActionDown: ClickableSpan? = null
    private var activeTextViewHashcode: Int = 0
    private var ongoingLongPressTimer: LongPressTimer? = null
    private var wasLongPressRegistered: Boolean = false

    interface OnLinkClickListener {
        fun onClick(textView: TextView, url: String): Boolean
    }

    interface OnWordSelectionListener {
        fun onWordSelected(word: String)
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(textView: TextView, text: Spannable, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (activeTextViewHashcode != textView.hashCode()) {
            activeTextViewHashcode = textView.hashCode()
            textView.autoLinkMask = 0
        }

        val clickableSpanUnderTouch = findClickableSpanUnderTouch(textView, text, event)
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            clickableSpanUnderTouchOnActionDown = clickableSpanUnderTouch
        }
        val touchOnText = clickableSpanUnderTouchOnActionDown == null

        var x = event.x.toInt()
        var y = event.y.toInt()

        x -= textView.totalPaddingLeft
        y -= textView.totalPaddingTop

        x += textView.scrollX
        y += textView.scrollY

        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                if (clickableSpanUnderTouch != null) {
                    highlightUrl(textView, clickableSpanUnderTouch, text)
                }

                if (touchOnText) {
                    touchDownX = x
                    touchDownY = y
                    val longClickListener = object : LongPressTimer.OnTimerReachedListener {
                        override fun onTimerReached() {
                            wasLongPressRegistered = true
                            val layout = textView.layout
                            val line = layout.getLineForVertical(touchDownY)
                            val offset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, touchDownX.toFloat())
                            if (offset <= textView.text.lastIndex &&
                                    !Character.isSpaceChar(textView.text[offset])) {
                                textView.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS)
                                val before = textView.text.subSequence(0, offset)
                                val after = textView.text.subSequence(offset, textView.text.lastIndex)

                                val wordStart = before.indexOfLast { !it.isLetter() } + 1
                                var wordEnd = after.indexOfFirst { !it.isLetter() }
                                if (wordEnd == -1) wordEnd = textView.text.lastIndex
                                else wordEnd += offset
                                val word = textView.text.subSequence(wordStart, wordEnd).toString()
                                if (word.isNotEmpty()) {
                                    wordSelectionListener?.onWordSelected(word)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    startTimerForRegisteringLongClick(textView, longClickListener)
                }
                return touchOnText
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                if (!wasLongPressRegistered && !touchOnText && clickableSpanUnderTouch === clickableSpanUnderTouchOnActionDown) {
                    dispatchUrlClick(textView, clickableSpanUnderTouch!!)
                }
                cleanupOnTouchUp(textView)
                return touchOnText
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
                cleanupOnTouchUp(textView)
                return false
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                if (event.x !in touchDownX - 5..touchDownX + 5 || event.y !in touchDownY - 5..touchDownY + 5) {
                    removeLongPressCallback(textView)
                }
                return touchOnText
            }
            else -> return false
        }
    }

    private fun cleanupOnTouchUp(textView: TextView) {
        wasLongPressRegistered = false
        clickableSpanUnderTouchOnActionDown = null
        removeUrlHighlightColor(textView)
        removeLongPressCallback(textView)
    }

    private fun findClickableSpanUnderTouch(textView: TextView, text: Spannable, event: MotionEvent): ClickableSpan? {
        var touchX = event.x.toInt()
        var touchY = event.y.toInt()

        touchX -= textView.totalPaddingLeft
        touchY -= textView.totalPaddingTop

        touchX += textView.scrollX
        touchY += textView.scrollY

        val layout = textView.layout
        val touchedLine = layout.getLineForVertical(touchY)
        val touchOffset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(touchedLine, touchX.toFloat())

        touchedLineBounds.left = layout.getLineLeft(touchedLine)
        touchedLineBounds.top = layout.getLineTop(touchedLine).toFloat()
        touchedLineBounds.right = layout.getLineWidth(touchedLine) + touchedLineBounds.left
        touchedLineBounds.bottom = layout.getLineBottom(touchedLine).toFloat()

        if (touchedLineBounds.contains(touchX.toFloat(), touchY.toFloat())) {
            val spans = text.getSpans(touchOffset, touchOffset, ClickableSpan::class.java)
            for (span in spans) {
                if (span is ClickableSpan) {
                    return span
                }
            }
            return null

        } else {
            return null
        }
    }

    private fun highlightUrl(textView: TextView, clickableSpan: ClickableSpan, text: Spannable) {
        if (isUrlHighlighted) {
            return
        }
        isUrlHighlighted = true

        val spanStart = text.getSpanStart(clickableSpan)
        val spanEnd = text.getSpanEnd(clickableSpan)
        val highlightSpan = BackgroundColorSpan(textView.highlightColor)
        text.setSpan(highlightSpan, spanStart, spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)

        textView.setTag(R.id.movementmethod_highlight_background_span, highlightSpan)

        Selection.setSelection(text, spanStart, spanEnd)
    }

    private fun removeUrlHighlightColor(textView: TextView) {
        if (!isUrlHighlighted) {
            return
        }
        isUrlHighlighted = false

        val text = textView.text as Spannable
        val highlightSpan = textView.getTag(R.id.movementmethod_highlight_background_span) as BackgroundColorSpan
        text.removeSpan(highlightSpan)

        Selection.removeSelection(text)
    }

    private fun startTimerForRegisteringLongClick(textView: TextView, longClickListener: LongPressTimer.OnTimerReachedListener) {
        ongoingLongPressTimer = LongPressTimer()
        ongoingLongPressTimer!!.setOnTimerReachedListener(longClickListener)
        textView.postDelayed(ongoingLongPressTimer, ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout().toLong())
    }

    private fun removeLongPressCallback(textView: TextView) {
        if (ongoingLongPressTimer != null) {
            textView.removeCallbacks(ongoingLongPressTimer)
            ongoingLongPressTimer = null
        }
    }

    private fun dispatchUrlClick(textView: TextView, clickableSpan: ClickableSpan) {
        val clickableSpanWithText = ClickableSpanWithText.ofSpan(textView, clickableSpan)
        val handled = onLinkClickListener != null && onLinkClickListener!!.onClick(textView, clickableSpanWithText.text)

        if (!handled) {
            clickableSpanWithText.span.onClick(textView)
        }
    }

    class LongPressTimer : Runnable {
        private var onTimerReachedListener: OnTimerReachedListener? = null

        interface OnTimerReachedListener {
            fun onTimerReached()
        }

        override fun run() {
            onTimerReachedListener!!.onTimerReached()
        }

        fun setOnTimerReachedListener(listener: OnTimerReachedListener) {
            onTimerReachedListener = listener
        }
    }

    class ClickableSpanWithText private constructor(val span: ClickableSpan, val text: String) {

        companion object {
            fun ofSpan(textView: TextView, span: ClickableSpan): ClickableSpanWithText {
                val s = textView.text as Spanned
                val text: String
                if (span is URLSpan) {
                    text = span.url
                } else {
                    val start = s.getSpanStart(span)
                    val end = s.getSpanEnd(span)
                    text = s.subSequence(start, end).toString()
                }
                return ClickableSpanWithText(span, text)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): BetterLinkMovementMethod {
            return BetterLinkMovementMethod()
        }
    }
}
```